# Decision trees in finding lower bounds of algorithms

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, lower-bound

One way to find the lower bound of a comparison based algorithm is to use the decision tree. U have two questions regarding this method :

1) We know that the height of the tree is path that connects the root node to the farthest leaf node ( longest path) which is equal to the number of comparisons made from the root node to the leaf node. Therefore , when we draw the tree for a comparison based algorithm we simply need to find the worst case time which corresponds to the largest path and therefore corresponds to the height of the tree. Now for any tree the height<=log2(number of leaf nodes) which is identical to Cworst(n) <= log2(n) and now we have a lower bound for the Cworst(n) and therefore the lower bound of the problem = log2(n). Is my understanding right ?

2) What is the meaning of having an inequality for Cworst(n) for a specific comparison problem? Does this means that for a specific comparison problem we can draw many trees and every time for the path of the worst case scenario the height will have a value that satisfies the equality ? This means that for a specific problem we can draw many different trees ?

Answer (score 2):

A decision tree illustrates the possible executions of an algorithm on a specific category of inputs. In the case of comparison-based sorting, a category would consist of all input lists of a certain size, so there's one tree for `n = 1`, one for `n = 2`, one for `n = 3`, and so on. Each tree is agnostic to the exact input values, but traces the possible directions the computation might go in depending on how the input values compare to each other.

One application of a decision tree is to reason about upper and lower bounds on the runtime complexity. As you mentioned, the height of a tree represents the upper bound on the runtime for that tree's input size, and if you can find a general relation between the input size and the tree height for all the decision trees of an algorithm, you have found an expression for the upper bound on the runtime. For example, if you analyze Bubble Sort, you will find that the decision tree for input size `n` has a height that's roughly `n * (n + 1) / 2`, so now you know that its runtime is bounded by `O(n^2)`. And since we have an upper bound on the general runtime, that also becomes an upper bound on the worst-case runtime.

When looking at a specific algorithm, we're usually interested in how fast it could possibly be (best case), how fast it usually is (average case), and how slow it could possibly be (worst case). And we often express the best case using a lower bound (Omega), because a lower bound for the best case is also a lower bound for the general runtime; similarly, we often express the worst case using an upper bound (O), because an upper bound for the worst case is also an upper bound for the general runtime. But we don't have to - O, Omega, and Theta are only mathematical tools that say something about a function, not caring that the function in our case describes a runtime complexity. So let's do something unusual: let's look at *all* the possible algorithms for a problem, and use decision trees to try to figure something out about *all* their worst-case complexities. Then, the interesting question isn't what the upper bound is, because it's easy to make extremely slow sorting algorithms. Instead, we're interested in the lower bound: what's the best worst case? Which algorithm makes the best guarantee about how slow it will be in the worst case?

Any sorting algorithm must be able to handle any order of its input elements. Each leaf node represents one particular final permutation (rearrangement) of the input elements, and with input size `n`, there are `n!` permutations. So a decision tree for input size `n` has at least `n!` leaf nodes. Any algorithm that wants to have a good worst case needs to have a balanced tree where all the leaf nodes are on the deepest or second-deepest level. And a balanced tree with `n!` leaf nodes must have a height of at `Omega(n lg n)`. Now we know something very interesting: for *any* comparison-based sorting algorithm, the *best* possible height (which represents the worst-case runtime) is *at least* `n lg n`! In other words, it is impossible to create a comparison-based sorting algorithm that always is faster than `n lg n`.

(Note: `height <= log2(leaf nodes)` is only the case for balanced trees. A tree's eight might be as much as the number of nodes minus one.)